# Is it possible to read/decode .avro uInt8Array Container File with Javascript in Browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, avro

I'm trying to decode an .avro file loaded from a web server.

Since the string version of the uInt8Array starts with
"buffer from S3 Objavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"Destination",..." 
I assume it's avro Container File

I found '[avro.js](https://github.com/rdblue/avro-js)' and '[avsc](https://github.com/mtth/avsc)' as tools for working with the .avro format and javascript but reading the documentation it sound's like the decoding of a Container File is only possible in Node.js, not in the browser.
(The FileDecoder/Encoder methods are taking a path to a file as string, not an uInt8Array)

Do I get this wrong or is there an alternative way to decode an .avro Container File in the browser with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I found a way using **avsc** with **broserify**

```js
avro.createBlobDecoder(blob, [{options}])
```

###### [avro.js - before browserifying]

```js
var avro = require('avsc');

const AVRO = {

decodeBlob(blob) {

        let schema, columnTitles, columnTypes, records = []

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            avro.createBlobDecoder(blob, {
                // noDecode: true
            })
                .on('metadata', (s) => {
                    schema = s
                    columnTitles = schema.fields.map(f => f.name)
                    columnTypes = schema.fields.map(f => f.type)
                })
                .on('data', (data) => {
                    records.push(data)
                })
                .on('finish', () => {
                    resolve(
                        {
                            columnTitles: columnTitles,
                            columnTypes: columnTypes,
                            records: records
                        }
                    )
                })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = AVRO
```

###### [package.json]

```json
"scripts": {
    "avro": "browserify public/avro.js --s AVRO > public/build/avro.js"
  }
```

###### [someOtherFile.js]

```js
//s3.getObject => uInt8array

const blob = new Blob([uInt8array])  //arr in brackets !important

const avroDataObj = await AVRO.decodeBlob(blob)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting!

Below is my integration of avro/binary with axios, in case it helps anyone else trying to implement browser side decoding:

[**before browserifying**]

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const avro = require('avsc')

const config = {
  responseType: 'blob'
};

const url = 'https://some-url.com'

axios.get(url, config)
.then(res => {
  avro.createBlobDecoder(res.data)
    .on('metadata', (type) => console.log(type))
    .on('data', (record) => console.log(record))
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```